# Problem with gedit

Tags: gedit

I am using ubuntu 16.04 LTS. 
`gedit` does not start when I type in the terminal:

```
gedit
```

I do get the following error:

```
(gedit:9955): GLib-GIO-ERROR **: Settings schema 'org.gnome.gedit.preferences.ui' does not contain a key named 'notebook-show-tabs-mode' Trace/breakpoint trap (core dumped)
```

I googled this but nothing fixed the problem (I tried to remove then install it...etc)

When I run:

```
apt-cache policy gedit
```

I do get:

```
gedit:
Installed: 3.18.3.is.really.3.10.4-0ubuntu13
Candidate: 3.18.3.is.really.3.10.4-0ubuntu13
Version table:
*** 3.18.3.is.really.3.10.4-0ubuntu13 500
    500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/mc3man/older/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
    100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
 3.18.3-0ubuntu4 500
    500 http://dz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
```

Comment: Are you installing gedit from the archives (ie with `apt` and you haven't added any other repos with gedit)? When you run `apt-cache policy gedit`, what is the result? The only thing I see online says this happens with gedit 3.4.2, but xenial uses 3.18.3 (http://disbauxes.upc.es/uncategorized/compile-that-fancy-old-version-on-your-newer-gnulinux-distro/).

Comment: @Larry Price: I edited the question

Comment: You installed an older version. See the removal instructions [here](https://launchpad.net/~mc3man/+archive/ubuntu/older) and reinstall from the repos.

Comment: @Jos : Sorry I do not see any instructions there

Comment: On the left. "To go back - Install & use ppa-purge `sudo ppa-purge ppa:mc3man/older` or just remove the ppa from sources, remove gedit & plugins packages, update sources & re-install repo versions"

Comment: @Jos Thank you , but I do not understand what do you mean (repos...etc)

Comment: `sudo apt install ppa-purge`, then `sudo ppa-purge ppa:mc3man/older`, then `sudo apt update && sudo apt install --reinstall gedit` should work.

Comment: @Jos: Wow Thank you that solved my problem :) .

Comment: I will post these instructions as an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For some reason, you installed `gedit` from an obscure ppa (called `ppa:mc3man/older`), instead of from the official repositories.

First, remove the references to the ppa. The easiest way to do that is to install a program called `ppa-purge`:

```
sudo apt install ppa-purge
```

then use it to remove the offending ppa:

```
sudo ppa-purge ppa:mc3man/older
```

Then the package sources need to be updated:

```
sudo apt update
```

and the official `gedit` can be installed:

```
sudo apt install --reinstall gedit
```

Done. The last two commands will now probably succeed, so I combined them into one line using the `&&` directive. This means: do the first command, then if successful, do the second command.

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt install --reinstall gedit
```